# Search spreadsheet by column, return rows

Tags: search, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to find the best script in terms of runtime to complete a task. I've got a decently large spreadsheet where I need to check values in certain known columns, and depending on a match case it returns that row. Ideally I'd like a new spreadsheet containing the returned rows.

I've got the spreadsheet opened by ID and I've got the sheet & range, but not sure the most efficient way to search through the specific columns and grabbing not just that value but the entire row.

Comment: Code speaks louder than words. Can you post the code that you have? If you have written something to start with, we can help with the optimization

Comment: thanks, your question lead me to answer my problem.. :)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can use the code below to search in a specific column. Code is self explanatory.

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = [ {name: "Search", functionName: "onSearch"} ];
  ss.addMenu("Commands", menuEntries);    
}

function onSearch()
{
    var searchString = "Test11";
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SheetName"); 
    var column =4; //column Index   
    var columnValues = sheet.getRange(2, column, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues(); //1st is header row
    var searchResult = columnValues.findIndex(searchString); //Row Index - 2

    if(searchResult != -1)
    {
        //searchResult + 2 is row index.
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().setActiveRange(sheet.getRange(searchResult + 2, 1))
    }
}

Array.prototype.findIndex = function(search){
  if(search == "") return false;
  for (var i=0; i<this.length; i++)
    if (this[i] == search) return i;

  return -1;
}
```

Comment: Can you shed some light on where to find the "findIndex" function?
Cannot see this function in the official documentation

Comment: @Aseem gautam. I want to check for array of items in a column. How i can use your function to find out if those array items don't exist on a column then insert them if they don't exist already ?

Comment: @matcheek - It looks like the function is defined within this script

Comment: Array.prototype.findIndex - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex

Answer (score 19):

You may want to use the Google Apps Script [textFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder) class.

This example function will search a string and show the row of the first occurrence in an alert dialog:

```
function searchString(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var search_string = "dog"
  var textFinder = sheet.createTextFinder(search_string)
  var search_row = textFinder.findNext().getRow()
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.alert("search row: " + search_row)
}
```

Comment: Note that this solution does not search in specific columns as asked in the question. It searches entire spreadsheet.

Comment: @Emin that function searches within a range.  That range can be a column or whatever you want.  Create the range for that single column and replace `sheet.createTextFinder()` with `range.createTextFinder()`

Answer (score 0):

[My lookup script on GitHub](https://github.com/preactive/GAS-Helper-Function/blob/master/Lookup_.js)

Usages:

`Lookup_(SheetinfoArray,"Sheet1!A:B",0,[1],"Sheet1!I1","n","y","n");`

`Lookup_(Sheetinfo,"Sheet1!A:B",0,[1],"return","n","n","y");`

`Lookup_(SheetinfoArray,"Sheet1!A:B",0,[0,1],"return","n","n","y");`

`Lookup_(Sheetinfo,"Sheet1!A:B",1,[1,3,0,2],"return","y","n","n");`

`Lookup_("female","Sheet1!A:G",4,[2],"Database!A1","y","y","y");`

`Lookup_(Sheetinfo,LocationsArr,4,[0],"return","y","n","y");`

`Lookup_(/RegEx+/i,LocationsArr,4,[0],"return","y","n","y");`

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Parameters Explaination:

-"Search_Key" - Can be be a string, array, or regex to lookup multiple things at once

-"RefSheetRange" - The Reference source of information.  Can be local sheet reference and range or an array of data from a variable.

-"SearchKey_RefMatch_IndexOffSet" - What column of information you are referencing of 'Search_Key' to 'RefSheetRange' data.

-"IndexOffSetForReturn" - Once a 'Search_Key' match has been found what columns of data will be returned from 'RefSheetRange'.

-"SetSheetRange" - Where are you going to put the chosen information from 'RefSheetRange' that matched 'Search_Key' OR you can use 'return' and when the function finishes it will return so you can output the function to a variable.

-"ReturnMultiResults" - If 'Y' Say you 'Search_Key' is 'NW' and you want to find every store in a chain that falls under the northwest in your dataset. So declaring 'Y' wont stop after it finds the first match it will keep searching throught the rest of the data.

-"Add_Note" - If 'Y' you are setting the results to a spreadsheet and not returning it to memory then it will set the first cell in the 'SetSheetRange' with a note of what and when.

-"Has_NAs" - If  'Y' it will put in '#N/A' the column where it did not find data for 'Search_Key' other wise it will leave the column blank.

Answer (score 0):

The combination of INDEX and MATCH should work:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$D$1000,MATCH(S2,$A$2:$A$1000,0))
```

S2 is a search key.

$A$2:$A$1000 is a range, where we will lookup.

$B$2:$D$1000 is a range, that we will return.

Keep in mind that numeric parts of $B$2:$D$1000 and $A$2:$A$1000 should match.

Answer (score 0):

I copied a scrip to search a Google Sheet but it will only return results if the search is the exact content of the cell. The cells have names. For example, row 1 have "John Doe". It will only bring results if I search for "John Doe". If I search just John or Doe or part of the name it will not return any resul.

```
    <div class="container">
        <br>
          <!-- ## SEARCH FORM ------------------------------------------------ -->
          <form id="search-form" class="form-inline" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
                <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchtext" name="searchtext" placeholder="Digite parte do nome">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Pesquisar</button>
              </form>
              <!-- ## SEARCH FORM ~ END ------------------------------------------- -->
        </div>
            <!-- ## TABLE OF SEARCH RESULTS ------------------------------------------------ -->
            <div id="search-results" class="table-responsive">
              <!-- The Data Table is inserted here by JavaScript -->
            </div>
            <!-- ## TABLE OF SEARCH RESULTS ~ END ------------------------------------------------ -->
          <br>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function onSearch()
{
    var searchString = "SD0023";
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 1"); 
    var column =1; //column Index   
    var columnValues = sheet.getRange(2, column, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues(); //1st is header row
    var searchResult = columnValues.findIndex(searchString); //Row Index - 2

    if(searchResult != -1)
    {
        //searchResult + 2 is row index.
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().setActiveRange(sheet.getRange(searchResult + 2, 3)).setValue("found here");
    }
}

Array.prototype.findIndex = function(search){
  if(search == "") return false;
  for (var i=0; i<this.length; i++)
    if (this[i].toString().indexOf(search) > -1 ) return i;

  return -1;
}
```

Made some small changes to the answer to search inline text.