# How to Change Status Column in Google sheet after Looking Up Reference Number

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am quite the 'newbie' programmer.  Trying to make a simple 'status change' upon a formSubmit event.  Many thanks for any help / assistance in my journey.

When the user fills out the form (https://docs.google.com/a/gregbartonmba.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSccMrgAWq95SOJO-1TC74lb4ri71aZzIWCMe342KmM66d6lqw/viewform), then the script runs.
- Finds the reference row with the ReferenceNumber in it (column B).
- Changes the value in the Status column (column A) to the new Status.

I have some example code that I attempted to modify but I'm too much of a newbie to get it right.  I think I'm close, but I'm somewhat lost...  Thanks.

The sheet with code can be found here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yXIggGwWg84CebcABTLxPcCd8YI7W7VJL7PmVkcjvJI/edit?usp=sharing

My coding attempt posted below...

```
function changeStatus(e) { 
   var Status = e.values[0];
   var ReferenceNumber = e.values[1];


// Look up the cell in the sheet that contains the ReferenceNumber.
// Find the instance in range B2:B that has the ReferenceNumber entered.
// Then, change the code of the left-most cell (Status) to the new "Status"     (entered from form submission)

/* Modified code from example at: 
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18482143/google-scripts-search-spreadsheet-by-column-return-rows
*/


 var searchString = ReferenceNumber;
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1yXIggGwWg84CebcABTLxPcCd8YI7W7VJL7PmVkcjvJI"); 
var column =1; //column Index   
var columnValues = ss.getRange(2, column, ss.getLastRow()).getValues(); //1st is header row
var searchResult = columnValues.findIndex(searchString); //Row Index - 2

if(searchResult != -1)
{
    //searchResult + 2 is row index.
             SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().setActiveRange(ss.getRange(searchResult + 2, 3)).setValue("found here");
}
}

Array.prototype.findIndex = function(search){
  if(search == "") return false;
   for (var i=0; i<this.length; i++)
    if (this[i].toString().indexOf(search) > -1 ) return i;

  return -1;


  /* If reference number entered does not exist, show browser pop-up that states "Reference Number
 Does not exist. Please enter a valid reference number." 
  */ 


 /* Catch any errors and then send them via email to greg@gregbartonmba.com.  
   Need error-catching in case the reference number does NOT exist in the 
   sheet.  
*/   

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**The first problem** is that the Spreadsheet classes all use 1-based indices, so you need to use

```
var column = 2; //column Index
```

**The second problem** is that you are trying to call getRange on a spreadsheet, you need:

```
var columnValues = ss.getSheetByName("MasterList").getRange(2, column, ss.getLastRow()).getValues();
```

**The third problem** is that you are running findIndex of a `String` on a `String[][]` object, an array of arrays of strings.
Even though you only have a column vector GAS uses a 2d array to be unambiguous as to the layout of the data.
Since in javascript arrays are only equal to each other if they refer to the exact same memory location and thus `[1] == [1]` being false we need to deep check the array.

Instead of `Array.prototype.findIndex` let's

```
Array.prototype.findIndexInColVector = function(search){
  if(search == "") return false;
   for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
    if (this[i][0].toString().indexOf(search) > -1 ) return i;
  return -1;
}
```

And then we can

```
var searchResult = columnValues.findIndexInColVector(searchString); //Row Index - 2
```

**The fourth problem**, then, when you found the row you are trying to select ranges on the spreadsheet, not the sheet

```
ss.getSheetByName("MasterList").getRange(searchResult + 2, 3).setValue("found here");
```

Of course to adjust the status you would then use

```
ss.getSheetByName("MasterList").getRange(searchResult + 2, 1).setValue(Status);
```

Comment: Thank you Robin!  I'm going to attempt to make the necessary corrections today.  Thank you very much for your answer and explanation.  Much appreciated! :)

Comment: Robin, first off, thanks so much for your input.  I have learned a lot already.  Still having a bit of a problem.  I believe the problem to be located in the line of code that follows.   var searchResult = columnValues.findIndex([searchString]);    This always ends up producing a value of -1, so the end result is that the word "Status" in cell A1 gets overwritten, no matter what value of ReferenceNumber is submitted.  I added some Logger.Log code to help me understand what was happening.  Standing by for your advice.  Thank you again. :)

Comment: You are very right, since you can't run indexOf with arrays, please check my updated answer.